# Regex, That Matches No more Than n Occurrences

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to find a Regex, that matches no more than n consecutive, say three, for example, occurrences of a character; in the case of three and character is "a":
abbaa - matches;
ammaaa - doesn't match(three consecutive a's), there is one "a", but whole expression must be discarded because three "a's"

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? What regex engine are you using?

Comment: Read some tutorials and experimenting on regex101.

Comment: For those cases where you know `n` is `1`, a simple question mark will suffice. `a?` matches zero occurrences and one occurrence of the letter a.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a character, or you can generalize it to all characters.
Also, not sure if you're trying to test or match the whole string, but assume
it's the whole string.

Generalized

`^(?:(\w)(?!\1{2})|\W)+$`

Explained

```
 ^                       # Beginning of string
 (?:                     # Cluster
      ( \w )                  # (1), a word character
      (?! \1{2} )             # Not 2 more of same in a sequence
   |                        # or,
      \W                      # Not a word character
 )+                      # End Cluster, 1 to many times
 $                       # End of string
```

You could substitute specific characters instead of `\w` and `\W`
by replacing what you want.

Example for  character `a` it would be `a` and `[^a]`.

`^(?:(a)(?!\1{2})|[^a])+$`

or more than one like  `[abc]` and `[^abc]`

`^(?:([abc])(?!\1{2})|[^abc])+$`

Comment: @TomaszMadry - Added an update note for specific character(s).

Comment: Thanks, seems to be this:)

Answer (score 19):

Use the `{m,n}` syntax (if your environment provides it, which it likely does.

`{m,n}` allows `m` to `n` (inclusive) occurrences of the previous character.

Examples:

`/a{0,3}/` matches 0 to 3 occurrences of `a`.

`/a{3,}/` matches 3 or more occurrences.

`/a{3}/` matches exactly 3 occurrences.

In the following example I've paired the above syntax with **negative lookahead** and **negative lookbehind**.

`(?<!a)a{0,3}(?!a)` matches 0 to 3 occurrences of `a` where there is no `a` before or after those 0-3 occurrences.

Comment: But the first example /a{0,3}/, matches also, let's say: xxaaaad; https://regex101.com/r/f54igA/1

Comment: Right, you have to be more specific with what you want to match if you want me to prescribe exact solutions. You would use the syntax I mentioned to build whatever regex you wanted. See my updated answer for another example.

Comment: Let me know if that last example is what you are looking for. I'm happy to discuss further and edit my question. Regexes are fun.

Comment: That works, cool. Interesting, that I've missed those negative looks syntax. I'm searching and reading now. Cheers.

Comment: Well, but still accepts abaaa - because of "a" in the expression; another answer seems to solve it.

Comment: It should match `abaaa`. It will match **no more than 3** and that satisfies it. The look behind and look ahead are making sure there is not another `a` **directly** before the group of 0-3 `a`'s. For example `aaaa` won't be accepted. Actually, the example in your question statement is wrong. **No more than 3 consecutive** means 3 in a row **IS** allowed.

Comment: Yes, about no more than three is a typo mistake, but problem is how to make it to not accept abaaaa - because there is more than three "a's".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139711/discussion-between-tomasz-madry-and-jakeehoffmann).